# Perforce claims file is different when it's not

Tags: windows, version-control, perforce, file-permissions

I have this file that seems to have gotten into a weird state. Perforce claims it's modified and unopened:

```
> p4 diff -se
data.xml
```

Normally, when a file is modified and unopened, I can use `sync -f` to fix it. But, for some reason, this particular file is being really stubborn:

```
> p4 sync -f data.xml
//Depot/Stream/data.xml#19 - refreshing data.xml

> p4 diff -se
data.xml
```

Like with `sync -f`, `clean` appears to work, but it still claims it's modified:

```
> p4 clean data.xml
//Depot/Stream/data.xml#19 - refreshing data.xml

> p4 diff -se
data.xml
```

Unsurprisingly, the same thing happens when I try to `reconcile -w`:

```
> p4 reconcile -w data.xml
//Depot/Stream/data.xml#19 - refreshing data.xml

> p4 diff -se
data.xml
```

If I use `reconcile` (without `-w`), the file is opened, but P4Merge shows the files as identical even without ignoring whitespace or line endings:

```
> p4 reconcile data.xml
//Depot/Stream/data.xml#19 - opened for edit

> p4 diff -se

> p4 diff -sa
data.xml
```

Using `revert` just puts it back into the state it was in before:

```
> p4 revert data.xml
//Depot/Stream/data.xml#19 - was edit, reverted

> p4 diff -sa

> p4 diff -se
data.xml
```

What gives? I had previously copied over this file without opening it for edit first by accident. Did that put it into an irreversible state, perhaps regarding Windows permissions?

I tried deleting the file (`del data.xml`) and getting it again, but the new copy created by Perforce had the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. The server's checksum of the file doesn't match its contents (which means a diff will always show it as different).  Your admin can check this with the `p4 verify` command.
2. The line endings in the file are inconsistent **and** you have the `share` LineEnd option, which essentially does an implicit `dos2unix` line ending conversion on every file whenever it's read from local disk.  If the `dos2unix` is a no-op the file will show as identical; if there are `\r`s in the file then their removal will show as a diff.

In either case submitting is likely to "fix" the file by creating a revision with a checksum that matches whatever is in your workspace -- but I'd recommend having an admin check `p4 verify` since if a file has gone bad it's likely to be a symptom of a larger problem (disk failure, etc).

Comment: I submitted the file and the problem went away. It must have been the second case, because I do have the share option, and it only affected me.

Comment: You can check this by diffing the revision you submitted vs the previous revision -- your revision should be the same as the previous one minus some `\r` characters (so it should show as identical with `diff2 -dl`, but have differing checksums and sizes).

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on @Samwise's answer a little:

If your workspace is configured with line ending configuration "Shared", but a file was at some point checked into the repository with windows (CrLf) line endings, then this will happen:

- When you get the files, perforce saves to your workspace exactly what it has/tracks (a text file, with windows line endings), because "shared" stipulates no sync-time conversion.
- If you were to save the file, it would convert the line endings to unix line endings (effectively run "dos2unix" as part of the submit).
- Therefore, when you run "reconcile" (for example), it highlights these windows-line-ending files as "Modified locally" and invites you to open them for edit and submit them.

This situation *presumably* arose when another user, with their workspace configured to "Unix" line ending mode, actually submitted a Windows-style file. Because the configuration "unix" stipulates no conversions at all, the "Cr" characters got saved on the server. This may have been accidental, or it may have been intentional.

The right course of action in this situation seems somewhat unclear:

- You can have reconcile work "correctly" by changing your Line Ending Characters setting to "unix" instead of "shared"; however, you then risk accidentally making things worse for everyone by accidentally checking in new CrLf files yourself later (assuming you're on Windows and some of your tooling tends that way) - like that previous user did
- You can really convert all these CrLf files to Lf (by opening them for edit & submitting them without changes, with your "shared" workspace setting) to prevent this issue in future, but that will appear as a spurious change for potentially many files. It **might also be the wrong thing to do** if anything in your tooling actually depends on these files containing the Cr characters - eg if they are checksummed against the output of some testing process.

Personally, I will be *temporarily* changing my workspace settings from "shared" to "unix", for reconcile operations only, and then switch back to "shared" for everyday perforce usage.